# MySQL Login Trouble

Tags: mysql

I just set up a new MySQL 5.1 Database Server on a Windows XP Box.  I set up a password during configuration.  However, now I can't seem to log in using the Administrative tool or command line, but there is one inconsistency that bugs me.

If I try to log in using the cmd line (mysql -u admin -p) or the MySQL Administrative Tool using the password I set up, it doesn't work

If I try to log in using the MySQL Command Line Client and the password I set up it works fine.

Why would this be the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just out of curiosity, the command line you give (mysql -u admin -p) is using the username "admin".  The master account for mysql is named "root".  Any chance that's your problem there?

Comment: You sir are a genius ... this is why .NET developers shouldn't be allowed to touch open source software ... I'm too stuck in my ways

Thank you!